# Calling an executable from a locally shared hard drive to convert images using Image Magick

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I am trying to use this line of code to convert an image using a .bat file. I put it in a locally shared hard drive and wish for everyone to be able to use it WITHOUT making everyone download image-magick. So I pasted the image-magick file into the S:\ and it still only works for me since I have it downloaded. I was wondering if I can call the convert.exe method in the image-magick folder in order to make it so that everyone can convert an image without downloading imagemagick.

```
convert "%1" -thumbnail 610x -unsharp 1.5x1.2+1.0+0.10 "%~p1resizedxLarge_%~n1.jpg"
```

^This code above only works IF image-magick is installed on my pc.

Thanks, in advance.

EDIT: Different people have a different folder hierarhcy.
I tried

```
 ..\ImageMagick\convert
```

but this error came up:

```
convert:  RegistryKeyLookupFailed 'CoderModulesPath'     
@error.module.c/GetMagick... etc
```

UPDATE: I tried adding

```
set ..\ImageMagick\=%%MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH%%; 
echo %%MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH%%
```

to it as the top line of code but it still doesn't work for pcs who do not have it installed.

Comment: I would try changing convert to the full path to convert on the shared drive.

Comment: So the problem with that is different people have different paths to the file. Ex if I did C:\ImageMagick, some others would have C:\Programs\ImageMagick etc. so I tried ..\ImageMagick\convert but it says:
convert:  RegistryKeyLookupFailed 'CoderModulesPath' @error.module.c/GetMagick... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard install of ImageMagick requires several DLLs to be installed and available with references in the registry.

ImageMagick does maintain a portable static version without these requirements.  Go to [ImageMagick Downloads](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) page and select one of the portable builds at the bottom.  If you use a relative reference to that executable, it should work on any computer.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. I also had to place the file inside the ImageMagick folder itself and move the convert.exe inside the folder too.

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to download ImageMagick portable, place it in the shared drive, then place my folder with the BAT files inside the ImageMagick Folder, and move over the convert.exe inside the folder w/ the bat files.